# EditText "maxLines" attribute doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a multiline EditText where users can type long sentences.
This is what I want: EditText with the height of 6 lines. From the 1st till 5th lines I want EditText's IME Action button to have "Enter" (go to a new line) button and on the sixth (last) line it should change into "Done" button so that when the user clicks on it, the soft keyboard should disappear. Is it even possible?

I used various combinations of imeOptions, inputType, maxLines, lines... but couldn't implement that. Any ideas?

Here is the XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="Your message ..."
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:lines="6"
    android:maxLines="6" />
```

When inputType is set to "textMultiLine" small IME action "Done" button changes to "Enter" (go to a new line) button. And it goes down endlessly.

**Current behavior:** EditText has height for 6 lines. In every line user can jump to the next line by pressing the "Return" button which throws the cursor the the next line. This behavior is OK, but when the user reaches to the 6th line, he/she still can press the "Return" button and go to the 7th line, which activates the scrolling feature of the EditText. I don't want this to happen.

**Behavior I want:** I want to block the User to get to the 7th line. And I want the Soft keyboard to have **"Done"** button when the user reaches to the 6th line. It doesn't matter if its phone, tablet or other.

[image: This is what I want]

[image: I don't want to go to the 7th line]

Here, user goes to the 7th line, and the first line disappears. Instead of EditText to get bigger I want it to remain as it is and prevent user to go to the 7th line pressing the "Enter" button. That's why on softKeyboard when user reaches to the 6th line, "Enter" button should change into "Done" button which closes the softKeyboard. Any practical ideas are welcome.

Comment: Could you clarify the intention? The user may want to enter less than 6 lines.

Comment: Also, the same text may be 6 lines on a tablet but for example 10 lines on a phone.

Comment: If the User wants to enter less than 6 lines, then it is fine...
I want the EditText to have height for 6 lines (which is done), also I want it not to jump to the 7th line when user presses the "Return" button.

Comment: i couldn't find any solution for that! just you can prevent user to goes the 7th line with `TextWathcher`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="Your message ..."
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:lines="6"
    android:maxLines="6"
    android:singleLine="false"
 />
```

Only add this `android:singleLine="false"` line in your `EditText`.

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work. Thanks though for the quick reply

Comment: I Think you want message box? Right?

Comment: What message box are you talking? I googled it and it showed AlertDialogs. Can you give me a link to that exact view you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="Your message ..."
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:lines="8"
    android:minLines="6"
    android:singleLine="false"
 />
```

Add android:minLines="6" line , Delete androidLmaxLines="6".

Answer (score 0):

What you want is doable only programmatically.
Add a `TextChangedListener` to your `EditText` and override `afterTextChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (editText.getLayout().getLineCount() >= 6) {
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    } else {
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but still no luck. When it reaches to the 6th line it goes to the if statement and sets imeOption to DONE but softkeyboard wasn't changed. Still "Enter" button is shown on the softkeyboard and still User can go to the 7th line.

Comment: Try with the updated answer. I can't check it right now, if it doesn't work I will try it in a few hours and find the solution.

Comment: It crashed, when it reached to the 6th line it crashed saying "NullPointerException... int android.text.Layout.getLineCount() on a null object reference". Okay, appreciate the effort

Comment: what happened, did you check the code, did it work? Maybe I was doing something wrong...