# The last character of Button's text is partially visible

Tags: android

I have a FrameLayout which contains an EditText and a Button.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="25" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forgottenPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_lightitalic"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:marginRight="16dp"                 // still, it gets cropped
        android:text="@string/password_button"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: question mark is partially visible]

I gave `padding=16dp` to the Button but somehow the **question mark is partially visible**. If I  make the phrase short like "Forgot it?" then the '?' mark fully visible. I didn't understand. I gave it even `marginRight=16dp`, still...

But when I don't set `fontFamily` attribute, again it is fully visible.

The confusion I have is that how come the last character gets cropped even though it has `padding` and `marginRight`. I even tried adding *space* after the question mark but nothing changed. Am I missing something?
**Edit:** I am actually using `strings.xml` for the button's text. When I add `space` after the '?' in the `strings.xml` it doesn't effect the text in the button, however, when text is hard coded and added `space` after the '?', question mark is fully visible again. But as it is said over and over *Hardcoded string is bad*.

I can't make my phrase short like "Forgot it?", because the app is in Turkish and the original phrase is relatively long. And also I *have to* use that font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your font is italic. If you want to insert a space character in XML file use `&#160;` after `?` like this : `?&#160;`.

Comment: Could you look through my other questions too?

Comment: witch one question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666650/edittext-maxlines-attribute-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the padding on your button. Remove the padding and try it out.

Comment: Didn't work, still the same... removed all the `padding`s, set `height=match_parent` and even added some spaces after the 'mark'.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is some clickable text, there's no need for a Button:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/forgottenPassword"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_lightitalic"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/password_button"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Notice that I added `clickable` and `focusable`.